# what pyqt widgets i can use wherein I can show picture and at the same time with text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have this box(QPlainTextEdit) wherein I can add multiline text. But if I want to add a picture along with text to this box, what pyqt widget I must use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `QTextEdit` for this, e.g.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
    window.setHtml('''
<h1>My document</h1>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p> 
<img src="resources/cat.jpg" alt="cat" width="500">
</p>
    ''')
    window.show()
    window.resize(700,700)
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Do I always need to use setHtml in order to insert the image? I mean can I just setText then add the image, is this possible?

Comment: With `setText` you can add both plain text or html. In that case `QTextEdit` will guess the format. `setPlainText` or `setHtml` will make this more explicit. You can an image later via `QTextBrowser.insertHtml`.